# Trying to wrap radio button text in Windows 8 Metro

Tags: windows-8, radio-button, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to wrap the radio button text for a Windows 8 Application.

This is the code that I have tried:

```
<RadioButton x:Name="ans2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="20"
 Margin="10,0,0,10" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="ansClick">
    <TextBlock Text="RadioButton" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
</RadioButton>
```

It is not working, any suggestions?

Comment: Can you clarify a little bit on what you mean by "it is not working"? The text wrapping does work if I constrain the `RadioButton` by setting say `Width="100"`.

Comment: There is nothing to clarify. It simply does not work.

Comment: I figured it out. I was still setting the radio button content and not the textBlock text. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<RadioButton>
   <TextBlock Text="This is text" TextWrapping="Wrap" ></TextBlock>
</RadioButton>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but making the code more condensed does not help my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  TextBlock txtAnswer = new TextBlock();
  txtAnswer.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
  txtAnswer.Text = "CONTENT";
  txtAnswer.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
  CheckBox CheckBoxAnswer = new CheckBox();
  CheckBoxAnswer.Content = txtAnswer;
```